# isFirstResponder is false even after becomeFirstResponder is true

Tags: swift, uikit, first-responder, becomefirstresponder

I'm debugging code to see why a WKWebView's instance doesn't become the firstResponder by doing the following:

```
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    let becomeFirstResponserResponse = super.becomeFirstResponder()
    print(becomeFirstResponserResponse, self.isFirstResponder)
    return becomeFirstResponserResponse
}
```

This prints out `true, false`. I've also verified that the web view's `window` property isn't `nil`.

As per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder), `becomeFirstResponder` returns `true if this object is now the first responder; otherwise, false.`. So I'd expect `self.isFirstResponder` to be `true`. What am I understanding incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't even finished returning from `becomeFirstResponder` yet! If you were to do your print inside a half-second `delay` you would find that we are in fact now returning `true` from `isFirstResponder` as well.

Comment: Thanks, @matt! I'll try adding the delay and seeing what happens. Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: It's not "behavior". You're in the middle of the call to `becomeFirstResponder`. That needs to take effect.